# Configurable product price equals zero

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

Today I've noticed that when an order is put through for a specific product it will show as zero on the invoice. But on the website it has the price as it is possible to see on the following images. Has anyone had this type of problem?
[image: Configurable price details]

[image: Configurable product page details]

[image: Main dashboard view]

Comment: Can you please share order details from admin side where one can see the whole calculation part? as you see there may be chance of any cart price rule or coupon used chances are there. In other hand, please check the advance pricing also as in Magento2+ if special price is less than price then it will be consider.

Comment: Hello Rajkumar. This is how it looks on the admin side https://imgur.com/KB0n9ae